# crosstab to fill with data of another column

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I dont arrive to populate a crosstab with data from another colum: maybe its not the solution...

```
  initial dataframe              final waited

   id  id_m     X
0  10    10     a
1  10    11     b               id_m  10  11  12
2  10    12     c               id              
3  11    10     d        ->     10    a    b   c
4  11    11     e               11    d    e   f
5  11    12     f               12    g    h   i
6  12    10     g
7  12    11     h
8  12    12     i
```

my code to help you:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'id': [10, 11,12]})
df_m = pd.merge(df.assign(key=0), df.assign(key=0), suffixes=('', '_m'), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)

# just a sample to populate the column
df_m['X'] =['a','b' ,'c','d', 'e','f','g' ,'h', 'i']
```

Comment: Check pivot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: thanks for the link, just the fact my column have string and not numeric..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original `df` is this

```
   id  id_m  X
0  10    10  a
1  10    11  b
2  10    12  c
3  11    10  d
4  11    11  e
5  11    12  f
6  12    10  g
7  12    11  h
8  12    12  i
```

And all you want is this

```
id_m 10 11 12
id           
10    a  b  c
11    d  e  f
12    g  h  i
```

You can `groupby` the `id` and `id_m` columns, take the `max` of the `X` column, then `unstack` the `id_m` column like this.

```
df.groupby([
    'id',
    'id_m'
]).X.max().unstack()
```

If you really want to use `pivot_table` you can do this too

```
df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='id_m', values='X', aggfunc='max')
```

Same results.

Lastly, you can use just `pivot` since your rows are unique with respect to the indices and columns.

```
df.pivot(index='id', columns='id_m')
```

References

- [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
- [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)
- [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

Comment: thanks for all solution, i have missed the fact agg was mean by default so doenst like the string...

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a bit more tricky since you have text as `values`, you have to explicitly tell pandas the `aggfunc`, you can use a `lambda` function for that like the following:

```
df_final = pd.pivot_table(df_m, index='id', columns='id_m', values='X', aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x) )


id_m    10  11  12
id          
10      a   b   c
11      d   e   f
12      g   h   i
```